# In spark, what kind of transformations necessit a shuffling (can imply a new stage)?

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

How to determine if a new transformation in spark causes the creation of a stage? is there a list of them ?

Answer (score -1):

There are some common operator like reducebykey,groupbykey that can cause to shuffle.You can visit spark offical website to learn more.